# How to trigger a Jenkins build after Deis deployment?

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, deis

I have a test suite set up on a Jenkins server that I would like to be executed after an app's Docker deployment to Deis (on AWS) is complete. There doesn't appear to be any documentation around achieving this, so I'm wondering if there is anywhere in the Deis post-deployment process where I might be able to invoke a build so that I could test my app on Jenkins every time it is deployed to Deis--perhaps I could start the build with a curl command, like the following:

`curl -X POST "http://jenkins.myserver.com/jenkins/job/PROJECT_NAME/buildWithParameters?APP_HOST=$host"`

but I don't know where I would include this build trigger within Deis. Is there perhaps a way to include a shell script to customize actions to be taken after a deployment has finished? I've also looked for Jenkins plugins for Deis, but there appears to be none. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: which Deis version? 1.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came here looking for a Jenkins plugin for Deis too :)
Regarding your question (if still relevant to you) - IMHO this can be achieved by running the Deis deployment itself from a jenkins job - then when it's complete (and successful) - trigger another jenkins job or step for the testing.

Comment: Great suggestion, and really funny that you mention that, because that's exactly how I ended up doing it :) cheers!